# Can I check what instance is currently 'sticked' to the ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have created a LBCookieStickinessPolicy for my ELB.

[image]

But I can't seem to find on any [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/) a command that retrieves the instances that are currently 'sticked' (I mean, the actual instance that the ELB is sending load now).

I only find the commands that create the policy itself (create-lb-cookie-stickiness-policy & create-app-cookie-stickiness-policy) ...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky sessions mean that a single user's web browser gets stuck to a single server instance (unless the server goes down or the user clears cookies). The ELB still distributes load across all the servers attached to it. The ELB would distribute multiple users across multiple server instances.

So there is no way to see what you are looking for because the ELB is always using all instances. Now if you just had a single user on your website, you could look at the server logs of each web server to determine which server that user is "stuck" to. In general you would need to look at the web server logs to see which servers are currently receiving traffic.

Comment: Thank you @Mark B, that was my horrible suspicion.

Comment: What is so horrible about it?

Comment: I need to know what is the instance(s) that is currently executing things without checking every instance